# How to search in list title which retrieved data from fire base

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, listview, search

I tried to figure out how to search in list title and I didn’t find a good solution pleas help me to get the answer [thi is my list title[i want to search in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVxjT.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rufq.jpg)
How?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I want something like this https://youtu.be/pUV5v240po0

Comment: Your data is coming from firebase? @Dalia

Comment: @rahulVFlutterAndroid yes

Comment: @Dalia have you check this package : https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_search

Answer (score 0):

For searching in firestore please refer the below package

This package is help for data searching

[pub.dev/packages/firestore_search](https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_search)